# Is it possible to disable chosen.js for a specific select box?

Tags: html-select, jquery-chosen

Given a certain event (say, a button click), I'd like to disable Chosen.js for a specific select box.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar requirement although it didn't require a button click, I just wanted to enable / disable Chosen for specific select boxes.

My solution is for each `select` element that you don't want to use Chosen with, add the CSS class `'no-chzn'`. Then in `chosen.jquery.js`, add the following lines to the constructor (this is near [line 533 in version 1.1.0](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/blob/master/chosen/chosen.jquery.js#L340)):

```
$.fn.extend({
    chosen: function(options) {
      if (!AbstractChosen.browser_is_supported()) {
        return this;
      }
      return this.each(function(input_field) {
        var $this, chosen;
        $this = $(this);
        if ($this.parent().hasClass("chosen-disable")) { return; } // Just add this line!
        chosen = $this.data('chosen');
        if (options === 'destroy' && chosen) {
          chosen.destroy();
        } else if (!chosen) {
          $this.data('chosen', new Chosen(this, options));
        }
      });
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

For example you have a select with class `no-chosen` and you do this:

```
$("select:not('.no-chosen')").chosen();
```

It means it takes all selects except the one with no-chosen class.